# Parsing XML Files doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm developing an app, where on the click of a button, the program calls information stored in an XML file to show in a `<span>` tag using JavaScript;

```
    function viewXMLFiles() {

        console.log("viewXMLFiles() is running");

        var xmlhttp = new HttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestInfo.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send;

        console.log("still running");

        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        console.log("getting tired");

        document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("documentList")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("documentList")[1].childNodes[1].nodeValue;

        console.log("done");
    }
```

and then the HTML to call it is (and where the XML file would be shown);

```
<button onclick = "viewXMLFiles();">View Document Info</button><br>

<span id = "documentList">
    <!--This is where the XML will be loaded into-->
</span>
```

the XML file is;

```
<document_list>

<document>

    <document_name>Holidays.pdf</document_name>

    <file_type>.pdf</file_type>

    <file_location></file_location>

</document>

<document>

    <document_name>iPhone.jsNotes.docx</document_name>

    <file_type>.docx</file_type>

    <file_location></file_location>

</document>

</document_list>
```

In the console, the first message comes up, but nothing happens and thats all that appears. But i'm really (like, *really* new) to XML and parsing and don't understand what's wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: where i said `new HttpRequest`?

Comment: ok i tried that, now it breaks on the `document.getElementById`... lines

Comment: `var xmlhttp = new HttpRequest();`

Comment: Yup i figured the prob in your last two lines .. See my answer and tell me whether it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the information for each Document, you would want something like this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getMyXML() {

  console.log("viewXMLFiles() is running");

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","TestInfo.xml",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

  console.log("still running");

  console.log("getting tired");

  document.getElementById("docname").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("filetype").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  document.getElementById("docname2").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("filetype2").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    console.log("done");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="getMyXML();" value="Get XML" />

<div id="doclist">
<h2>Document 1</h2>
<label>Docname: </label><span id="docname"></span><br/>
<label>Filetype: </label><span id="filetype"></span><br/>

</div>

<div id="doclist">
<h2>Document 2</h2>
<label>Docname: </label><span id="docname2"></span><br/>
<label>Filetype: </label><span id="filetype2"></span><br/>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this because You have only one childnode for documentlist

```
document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("documentList")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("documentList")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26548/discussion-between-prasath-k-and-megan-sime)

Answer (score 2):

Note:

1. Use getElementsByTagName
2. There is no documentList tag in your xml
3. Tag document is the only array in your xml not document_list

   ```
   function viewXMLFiles() {

     console.log("viewXMLFiles() is running");

     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET","TestInfo.xml",false);
     xmlhttp.send();
     xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

     console.log("still running");


     var getData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document");
     console.log("getting tired");

     document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = getData[0].getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     document.getElementById("documentList1").innerHTML = getData[1].getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

       console.log("done");
   }
   ```

Add one more span with id documentList1 to execute the above code

Comment: ok thanks a lot, and this works, but i was looking for it to show everything in the XML file. do i need to repeat the `document.getElementById("documentList").innerHTML = getData[0].getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("documentList1").innerHTML = getData[1].getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` lines for the other tags in the file?

Comment: Yes you should repeat for each tag in the file

Comment: You should repeat for the tags document_name,file_type and file_location but you can use for loop to get the elements under document tag .. I mean for loop instead of getData[0],getData[1]....etc

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in:

```
var xmlhttp = new HttpRequest();
```

It should be:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot - that works, but now there's a problem with the final two lines of JavaScript :S can you see a problem?